# Does the Marketing Cloud API allow simultaneous log-ins by the same user?

Tags: api

I'm determining if multiple API users are required if multiple integration points to the Marketing Cloud are being built.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple simultaneous logins by the same user, however the part you will need to be worried about is the increase risk of getting errors due to query limits. Also, multiple client applications share the same session so if one client calls logout() it would invalidate the session of all the other applications. Just some things to think about when determining your integration.

Here is a resource that may help:
http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/implementation_considerations.htm